# How to prevent node from running out of memory when bundling js for React Native

Tags: react-native, clojurescript, cljsrn

When bundling js for React Native using ClojureScript I got the following error. It seems that node runs out of memory when bundling the javascript bundle. This is probably more likely to happen when using ClojureScript since the resulting js files are generally bigger than vanilla js.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

<--- Last few GCs --->

  152689 ms: Mark-sweep 1369.3 (1434.8) -> 1362.8 (1434.8) MB, 2794.5 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  155498 ms: Mark-sweep 1362.8 (1434.8) -> 1362.9 (1434.8) MB, 2808.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  158508 ms: Mark-sweep 1362.9 (1434.8) -> 1362.8 (1434.8) MB, 3010.8 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  161189 ms: Mark-sweep 1362.8 (1434.8) -> 1362.8 (1434.8) MB, 2680.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0xd4b9fdc9e59 <JS Object>
    1: visitQueue [/Users/myproj/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:~130] [pc=0x3e89a3f7bd28] (this=0x24a5ec659101 <a TraversalContext with map 0x157972399611>,queue=0x24a5ec659149 <JS Array[1]>)
    2: node [/Users/myproj/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:~150] [pc=0x3e89a3e4f23a] (this=0x387a6b7f4301 <JS Function traverse (SharedFunction...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

<--- Last few GCs --->

  238422 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.8 (1434.8) -> 1364.8 (1434.8) MB, 3377.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  241834 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.8 (1434.8) -> 1364.8 (1434.8) MB, 3412.3 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  245313 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.8 (1434.8) -> 1364.8 (1434.8) MB, 3478.7 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  248639 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.8 (1434.8) -> 1364.8 (1434.8) MB, 3326.4 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x266dabec9e59 <JS Object>
    1: new constructor(aka NodePath) [/Users/myproj/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js:~61] [pc=0x108980041705] (this=0x1cedf9a7ef69 <a NodePath with map 0x3182f379cf21>,hub=0x266dabe04189 <undefined>,parent=0x3d43337ab49 <a Node with map 0x3182f3798489>)
    3: get [/Users/myproj/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js:~87] [pc=0x10898...

[node-haste] Encountered an error while persisting cache:
> Error: Uncaught error in the transformer worker: /Users/myproj/node_modules/react-native/packager/transformer.js
>     at _transform.then.catch.error (/Users/myproj/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/JSTransformer/index.js:99:31)
>     at tryCallOne (/Users/myproj/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
>     at /Users/myproj/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
>     at flush (/Users/myproj/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
/Users/myproj/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Uncaught error in the transformer worker: /Users/myproj/node_modules/react-native/packager/transformer.js
    at _transform.then.catch.error (/Users/myproj/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/JSTransformer/index.js:99:31)
    at tryCallOne (/Users/myproj/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/myproj/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/myproj/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution for iOS is to edit the following file: `ios/YourProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and change the following line (~600)

```
shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh";
```

to

```
shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY='node --max_old_space_size=4092'\n../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh";
```

Comment: That line doesn't exist in my project.pbxproj file. Mine looks something like
`shellScript = "\"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files......`

Comment: @vikeri: thank you for saving my life. I search every where for the syntax. Finally I found yours.

Comment: Still 'heap out of memory'. Did anyone figure out another fix?

Answer (score 5):

For android, this can also be set in android/app/build.gradle by adding:

```
project.ext.react = [
   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node", "--max-old-space-size=4096"]
]
```

note that this must be added above the following line:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to disable optimizations by setting `--dev true` for production builds. This has performance drawbacks, but in my experience they are acceptable. Dev mode also enables a number of runtime checks. You can disable them by changing the **DEV** constant at the top of the bundle output, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Patch jsbundle to set __DEV__ to false

import sys, re

print(re.sub(r'__DEV__\s*=\s*true;', "__DEV__=false;",
        sys.stdin.read()))
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found way to generate Signed APK in re-natal project.
For this we must edit file in `node_modules/react-native/react.gradle`

Change 84-th row in this file.
From

```
commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, "node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, *extraPackagerArgs)
```

To this

```
commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, "--max-old-space-size=4096", "node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, *extraPackagerArgs)
```

To create production build you must use

```
lein prod-build
```

After compiling of ClojureScript use this commands:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The generated APK can be found under `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`, and is ready to be distributed.

Comment: @GarimaMathur Are you sure you use ClojureScript?

Answer (score 0):

For `iOS`, with **react-native 0.59.0** works by editing on `ios/YourProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

this line

```
shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh";
```

with

```
shellScript = "export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh";
```