# react native - add --max_old_space_size to iOS project when build release

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

I am able to add `--max_old_space_size` in Android for release build in React Native. However, I am not able to add it for the iOS build release. I found the answer but it is not working.

[React Native build fails with "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"](https://intercom.help/appcenter/build/react-native/react-native-build-fails-with-fatal-error-call_and_retry_last-allocation-failed-javascript-heap-out-of-memory)

Here is some useful link:

[React Native ios build : Can't find node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492197/react-native-ios-build-cant-find-node)

If you have any suggestions, please let me know. I am willing to hear from you guys.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in this link:

[Javascript out of memory heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198511/how-to-prevent-node-from-running-out-of-memory-when-bundling-js-for-react-native/38198512)

Change:

```
shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh";
```

To:

```
shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY='node --max_old_space_size=8192'\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh";
```

In:

```
ios/YourProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Please be patient because the project cost a lot of time when build release. More than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

By adding Max_old_heap_size in xcode you can resolve.

[Please Check the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsMbW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add Max-old-space-size at react-native-xcode.sh

[ -z "$NODE_BINARY" ] && export NODE_BINARY="node"

[ -z "$NODE_ARGS" ] && export NODE_ARGS="--max-old-space-size=4096"

[ -z "$CLI_PATH" ] && export CLI_PATH="$REACT_NATIVE_DIR/cli.js"

[ -z "$BUNDLE_COMMAND" ] && BUNDLE_COMMAND="bundle"

Comment: thank you for your answer. The `react-native-xcode.sh` is belonged to node_modules folder, which will be removed if we type `npm install`. Your answer is worked but it is not 100% safe

Comment: I cannot see the attachment, you must have at least 10 reputation point to upload image if I remember correctly

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: I see it now. I will have a try on it, bro. But this solution is only for release

Comment: node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

Comment: While I agree this answer is slightly unsafe its the ONLY one that actually worked for me.

Changing the build scripts did nothing to help the failure of xcode archiving which was failing due to memory issues.

Only changing the underlying package script to include the help size worked.

Will have to keep a manual note to re-add anytime we change a package on imac build server. 

Yay.....